# Уменьшение картинки php or js

Tags: php, javascript

Необходимо уменьшить картинки на php или js, для того чтобы уменьшенные копии не были ни сжаты, ни размыты, вот пример:

1. Тут все картинки классные http://www.auto.az/
2. А вот тут бред какой-то http://avtomobil.az/

Помогите сделать так как на auto.az или подскажите хотя бы с чего начать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На обоих ваших примерах картинки не айс.

Целесообразно делать такое все же в PHP, разово, при загрузке на сайт. Не в JS.

Четкость - это уже хитрость алгоритма.

Например, алгоритм "Least-Squares Image Resizing Using Finite Differences" дает хороший результат практически всегда. Описание вот: http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/munoz0101.pdf Сможете его реализовать?

Но в простейшем случае чаще всего используют сочетания двух процедур - изменения размера и повышения резкости (например, широко известным методом Unsharp Mask). Это настолько распространенная вещь, что найти готовые процедуры не проблема - http://www.sitepoint.com/crop-and-resize-images-with-imagemagick/